# Tree structure: immutability

Tags: javascript, typescript, tree, immutability, immutable.js

Yesterday I was poundering about a dilemma that I have.

For writing a tree library, I want to use ImmutableJS internally for several reasons (immutability (obviously), efficient internal undo stack because of persistent data structure, convenient collection types with manipulation & lookup methods).
Since my library will depend on ImmutableJS, I considered using immutability for the public api as well. However I find myself in some sort of a dilemma.

By allowing an immutable api, I allow consumers to access cloned tree states and I'm not sure if that is desired behaviour.
Multiple tree/node states will be maintained from within the library (undo/redo stack). Allowing users to multiple tree/node versions may open up bugs and dilemmas.
For example:

```
var node1 = new Node(); 
var tree1 = new Tree(); 
var tree2 = tree1.setRootNode(node1); 
var node2 = node1.append(new Node());
```

Now the consumer is in theory capable of transforming two tree/node instances that would in essence refer to the same identity (there is only 1 'working tree'). The 'old' version of the tree is internally managed by the undo-stack, I don't think that it is desirable to allow consumers to change an old version of the tree, but yet they would be able to.

On the other hand, I find the following to be more transparent, since there is no confusion over different tree / node versions in the public api:

```
var node1 = new Node(); 
var tree1 = new Tree(); 
tree1.setRootNode(node1); 
node1.append(new Node());
```

This seems much more undubious to me... I also noticed that jQuery `append` works with mutable nodes, not sure if there is similar reason for this.
If the consumer really wants a clone, then it could simply be done with for example:

```
var tree2 = tree1.clone();
```

But here intention is clear, and the second tree would also get its own internal undo stack.
What is your view? Should I still use immutability in the public api?
I ask this question because I know how much users favour immutability.

Comment: I ran into this exact problem today. Was hoping to find an easy solution. I think the key is to use integer offsets instead of object references. So that there is a sequence of all nodes, and the parent for a number is just an integer that points to a node in that sequence.